# Printing dataframe name within a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames. I want to perform a bunch of operations within a for loop but before that, I need to extract the string name of each dataset to use as variable/data frame name suffixes.

```
for(i in dflist) { 
  
  suffix<- deparse(substitute(i))
    print(suffix)
  }
```

However, my output shows as the following:

```
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
```

I know that this is because of R's lazy evaluation framework. But how do I get around this limitation and get R to assign the names of data frames in dflist to the suffix variable ?

Comment: `names(dflist)` or `names(dflist)[i]`? You shouldn't need to do any deparse(substitute()) nonsense... that's half the point of putting them in a list!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `names`, as in your case:

```
for(i in names(dflist)){
    print(i) # to print the name in your list
# then if you want to extract the data frame from the list
    df <- data.frame(dflist[names(dflist)==i])
  }
```

the only problem is that you'll have to rename the columns by their old names.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Try to understand what `elements` of a list are and how `indexing` works when you works with lists.

**example data**

```
dflist <- list( 
     name_df1 = data.frame(a = 1:3)
    ,name_df2 = data.frame(mee = c("A","B","C","D"))
    )
```

**understand list elements**

What do we access with `index i` in a for loop over a list?

```
for(i in dflist){ 
  print(class(i))
  print(names(i))  
}
[1] "data.frame"
[1] "a"
[1] "data.frame"
[1] "mee"
```

`index` extracts an object of class (here) data frame.

**your case**

```
for(i in dflist){ 
  suffix <- names(i)
  print(suffix)  
}
[1] "a"
[1] "mee"
```